# I am experiencing problems with the dateTimePicker in other languages?

Tags: c#, datetime, datetimepicker

I have an application that I made on an English Language laptop. It works perfectly and handles all the Convert.ToDateTime functions properly. But when it is used on a Japanese Language laptop, which is my client's settings, it displays an error String was not recognized as valid DateTime. What to do?

Comment: Please post your code that raise the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is 12/12/2012 will be correct for both japanese and English but 13/12/2012 may error for japanese as there are only 12 Months and the date is taken as MM/dd/YYYY format !

Try this:

```
DateTime Todate = DateTime.ParseExact("22/08/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
Todate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"); // output in your chosen format.
```

The point is that Todate is a DateTime object, so it actually stores the date and time internally as a big number. If you want to display it in a certain format, then you convert it to a string. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to convert the `Text` property of a `DateTimePicker` to `DateTime`; just use the `Value` property (which is already of the correct data type).

Likewise, if you are trying to set the value of the control, don't parse the date from a string. Store the value as a `DateTime` and simply set the `Value` property accordingly.